# asp.net application deployment on aws beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an asp.net framework web application on AWS beanstalk. I uploaded a zip containing two other zips of asp.net framework web applications. My aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json is written as follows:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "iisConfig": {
        "appPools": [
          {
            "name": "AppPoolName",
            "recycling": {
              "regularTimeInterval": 10
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    "deployments": {
        "msDeploy": [
        {
            "name": "site_deployment",
            "parameters": {
                "appBundle": "Site.zip",
                "iisPath": "/",
                "appPool": "AppPoolName",
                "iisWebSite": "Default Web Site"
            } 
        }
        ,
        {
            "name": "webservices_deployment",
            "parameters": {
                "appBundle": "WebServices.zip",
                "iisPath": "/"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
  }
```

I've got this error : 
Error messages running the command: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="C:\staging\Site.zip" -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='Default Web Site/' Error: Source does not support parameter called 'IIS Web Application Name'. Must be one of (). Error count: 1.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly check your webapp package file contains a parameters.xml file?.

If It contains, this file should have a parameter "IIS Web Application Name".

If not, you could export zip from VS which automatically create parameters.xml with "IIS Web Application Name".